# Attachment mail using php mail()?

Tags: php

This is the code snippet i am using to send an email with attachment,but it is not working.The output i am getting includes a large amount of hashcode(i think so).What should be done to send screenshot.rar as attachment ?

```
<?php

      $to = "abc@gmail.com";

      $subject = "A test email";

      $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));

      $headers = "From: xyz@gmail.com\r\n";

      $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";

      $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("screenshot.rar")));

      $output = "
      --PHP-mixed-$random_hash
      Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary='PHP-alt-$random_hash'
      --PHP-alt-$random_hash
      Content-Type: text/plain; charset='iso-8859-1'
      Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

      Hello World!
      This is the simple text version of the email message.

      --PHP-alt-$random_hash
      Content-Type: text/html; charset='iso-8859-1'
      Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

      <h2>Hello World!</h2>
      <p>This is the <b>HTML</b> version of the email message.</p>

      --PHP-alt-$random_hash--

      --PHP-mixed-$random_hash
      Content-Type: application/zip; name=screenshot.rar
      Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
      Content-Disposition: attachment

      $attachment
      --PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";

      echo @mail($to, $subject, $output, $headers);

    ?>
```

Comment: Your life would be much easier if you used a premade mailing solution, like PHPMailer.

Comment: i have never used it.Can you tell me how to use it in xampp?

Comment: Download the script, and look up some tutorials for it, there are a lot of them around the web, it's quiet popular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP Mailer is the best option for this matter. Try it. [Click Here](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial)

Ex:

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'jswan';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->AddAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->AddAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->AddReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->AddCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->AddBCC('bcc@example.com');


$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->AddAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->AddAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML


$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
echo 'Message has been sent';
?>
```

This is sample code provide by phpmailer.

Answer (score 0):

[Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.html) library would be ideal for this. Libraries are written precisely so that people in your situation don't have to create these packages from scratch, take advantage of them.

The documentation is really good (linked above) and you just have to download Zend Framework and include it on your `include_files` in php.ini.